# php in_array() or array_search() not working

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a simple php script to look for an element in an array like

```
    $restricted = array('root/base', 'root2' ); 
    print_r($restricted);
    if( array_search('root/base', $restricted) ){
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
```

But I am always getting the following output

```
Array ( [0] => root/base [1] => root2 ) 0
```

This means that the array_search is failing to find the element in the given array. Can anybody show some light on whats happening?

I tried to replace array_search() with in_array() also. But that too returned the same error.

Comment: in_array works for me

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question -- this person's problem is mistaking the value 0 for FALSE. The OP's problem in the "duplicate question" cited is mistaking arrays for comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From PHP DOC

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

The index is `0` that is why you think its fails

Use

```
array_search('root/base', $restricted) !== false
```

Comment: but why in_array() fails?

Comment: i don't see `in_array` in your example but see http://eval.in/31491